# I am getting content missing error "JAXRSApplicationClass" when deploying adapter?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, adapter

I am getting this error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content
>   was found starting with element 'JAXRSApplicationClass'. One of
>   '{runOnNode, debugPort, connectivity}' is expected.

adapter xml is here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2016. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<mfp:adapter name="CardServices"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>CardServices</displayName>
    <description>CardServices</description>

    <JAXRSApplicationClass>com.slap.bank.ServicesApplication</JAXRSApplicationClass>
    <property name="DB_url" displayName="Database URL" defaultValue="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.15:1521:xe"  />
    <property name="DB_username" displayName="User Name" defaultValue="BANK_NEW"  />
    <property name="DB_password" displayName="Password" defaultValue="BANK_LOCAL"  />


</mfp:adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this doc https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_structure_of_adapter_xml_file.html a `connectivity` element before `JAXRSApplicationClass` is required

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deploying in Worklight 7, try deploying in Worklight 8. It will resolve the issue.